# Logar com usuário da rede

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Ao abrir a página que estou construindo, o usuário que estiver logado pela rede, ele mesmo fará o login na página com esse usuário, mas sem ter que abrir uma página para isso, ou seja, meu sistema terá que pegar o cara na rede e dar acesso a ele ao portal/sistema. Eu uso:

VS2013 - MVC5 - Bootstrap - C# - SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 7):

Configure seu arquivo `Web.config` com o seguinte:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```

O usuário pode ser obtido usando:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Veja mais aqui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998358.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Cara, se a autenticação for rolar com um Active Directory, o VS Studio te auxilia, dê uma olhadinha nesse tutorial para criar um Single Sign On usando [Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) com Entity Framework.

O Active Directory é uma implementação de serviço de diretório no protocolo LDAP que armazena informações sobre objetos em rede de computadores e disponibiliza essas informações a usuários e administradores desta rede. (Fonte: Wikipedia)

Exemplo Aqui: [Windows Azure Active Directory](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory)

Com esse caminho das pedras eu desenvolvi um web app com autenticação com o servidor de onde trabalho.