# Login com usuário da rede(AD)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, segurança, active-directory

Preciso logar o usuário em meu sistema, com o usuário que está logado na rede da empresa. Nunca fiz isso e estou tendo dúvida em como pegar usuário no AD. Estou fazendo pesquisa na net e ainda não consegui entender em como buscar esse usuário. A pergunta é: Como eu pego o usuário logado na rede e logo no meu sistema? Uso MVC5, Visual Studio 2013, C#.

Então, peguei esse código em um outro forum e deu certo, mas tem uma coisa chata ainda a resolver. Ele me traz o domínio e/ou o nome da máquina, nesse formato: Dominio\Usuario. Como eu removo o domínio e a barra? Abaixo a minha solução:

```
public ActionResult CadastroCargo()
        {
            ViewBag.User = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Cara, eu respondi essa pergunta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28779/logar-com-usu%C3%A1rio-da-rede/28946#28946)

Answer (score 6):

Se você for criar um novo projeto, basta usar o template de projeto ASP.NET Web Application, escolher MVC, ao lado existe a opção Change Authentication :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então escolha a opção Windows Authetication , que é para aplicações intranet.

Clique em ok, e pronto. Você tem uma Web Application pegando o usuário do AD.

Perceba que no Web.Config da aplicação a parte de autenticação estará como authetication mode="Windows" :

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Caso queira limitar quais usuários ou grupos irão acessar seu site, basta adicionar as regras, por exemplo :

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="meudominio\Grupo1,meudominio\Grupo2" />
      <allow users="meudominio\usuario1" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Dessa forma você bloqueia o acesso para todos os usuários, mas permite a todos os usuários do Grupo1 e Grupo2, e o usuário Usuario1 o acesso.

Simples assim.

Comment: Isso, mude para `<authentication mode="Windows" />`. Seu projeto já buscava os usuários de algum lugar?

Comment: Não, estou começando a fazer agora. Eu estava criando uma tela de login, mas pediram para busca do AD. Mas eu vou precisar tratar esse usuário em uma tabela que eu fiz aqui para o sistema, mas isso já é outra coisa.

Comment: Tranquilo, basta associar nessa tabela o login do AD do usuário. E no C# você pode pegar o usuário que está acessando seu site usando `User.Identity.Name`. Aí o resto você faz o que quiser. Se você precisar de regras de acesso customizadas  a partir de dados de uma tabela, você também pode criar um RoleProvider customizado, que não passa de uma classe que implementa a interface RoleProvider. E no Web.Config informar que seu roleManager será do tipo de seu roleProvider customizado.

Comment: Então, fui pegar esse cara na minha controller e está vindo vazio. Eu estou em uma máquina não logada na rede, mas com meu usuário de acesso. Acho que dessa forma não vai funcionar, certo? Será na rede da empresa, mas desenvolvo em minha máquina particular(notebook).

Comment: Fiz uma edição no meu post para mostrar a solução.

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Se a sua intenção é apenas escrever na tela o nome do usuário sem o domínio na frente do nome do usuário, pode usar o seguinte comando

```
System.Environment.UserName
```