# Logar automaticamente na aplicação utilizando Windows Autentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, autenticação, active-directory

Preciso fazer minha aplicação ASP.NET logar automaticamente utilizando credenciais do Windows (Active Directory), exatamente igual ao Portal do *SharePoint* faz.

No Visual Studio já tem um *template* (Framework 4.5) onde ele cria um *WebApplication* com `Windows Autentication`, o exemplo funciona perfeitamente na minha máquina, mas se eu publicar esse site numa maquina na rede, que está mesmo domínio da minha maquina, ele não funciona. Ele abre a tela de login, e mesmo assim não reconhece meu usuário e senha da rede. É como se ele não "enxergasse" o meu controlador de domínio.

Pelos exemplos que eu encontrei na internet, basta eu colocar as seguinte linhas no meu `Web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Também é necessário adicionar a opção de `Windows Autentication` no IIS.

Já efetuei todos esse passos, mas sem sucesso. Talvez tenha alguma configuração adicional no IIS que esteja faltando para o meu exemplo funcionar.

Fiz um teste utilizando minha máquina como servidor e acessando de outras maquinas da rede. Algumas máquinas entraram sem solicitar usuário e senha, e algumas abriram a tela de login. Seria alguma configuração na máquinas clientes? Eu verifique em Opções da internet e em todas as maquinas em <kbd>Segurança</kbd> > <kbd>Autenticação do Usuário</kbd>, está marcada a opção "Logon automático somente na zona da intranet"

Comment: Já respondi essa aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28783/2999

Comment: Se aparece o popup para digitar o usuário / senha, o servidor web não está no mesmo domínio do AD.

Comment: Como mencionei, eu já fiz as mudanças necessário no Web.config, e tudo funcionou perfeitamente na minha máquina. No entanto quando faço o deploy para o servidor, a aplicação não consegue efetuar o login, fica exibido a tela de login.

Comment: Fiz um teste utilizando minha maquina como servidor e acessando de outras maquinas da rede. Algumas maquinas entraram sem solicitar usuário e senha, e algumas abriram a tela de login. Seria alguma configuração na maquinas clientes? Eu verifique em Opções da internet e em todas as maquinas em Segurança -> Autenticação do Usuário, está marcada a opção "Logon automático somente na zona da intranet"

Comment: Poderia por favor incluir esse comentário acima na pergunta? Vou indicar pra reabertura.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, a reabertura só devia ser iniciada uma vez esclarecido *dentro da pergunta* porque não é uma duplicata... Você mesmo pode editar a pergunta para incorporar as novas informações do Cristiano.